# Zero-and-one inflated beta regression vs. binomial GLMM?

Tags: proportion, glmm, lme4-nlme, zero-inflation, beta-distribution

I appreciate some help with deciding whether I should (and how to) construct a zero-and-one-inflated beta regression model. I want to use R to test the hypothesis that there is a `condition` * `age` interaction effect on `investment`.

`investment` can be none (i.e. 0), half (i.e. 0.5) or all (i.e. 1). This makes `investment` non-binomial, and, strictly speaking, inappropriate for a GLMM with `family = binomial`. It looks like I should use `gamlss()` to run a beta regression with `family = BEINF`.

`condition` is a factor with 3 levels.
`age` is a continuous variable. 
There is another fixed effect `sex`, and a random effect `groupID`

the mu.formula of a `gamlss` beta regression should look like this: 
`investment ~ condition * age + sex + re(random = ~1 | groupID)`

I have three questions:

1. Since my goal is hypothesis testing other than model selection, shall I just use something like `drop1` to test the effect of each predictor?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, how should I specify sigma.formula, nu.formula and tau.formula? (I am aware of the function `stepGAICAll.A` for selecting the best model, but that's kind of a forward model selection and my goal isn't model selection anyway).
3. Let's forget beta regression for the moment. How justified I am if I just go ahead and use a binomial GLMM via `lme4`? The two reasons for this include:

(1) `investment` has only three possible values (0, 0.5 and 1), it's clearly not a binary response, but it's not far from it. It doesn't look like a true frequency either. Even if I stick with zero-and-one-inflated beta regression, I have a hard time understanding what the mu.formula means? Does it mean the probability of `investment` equals 0.5?

(2) a quote from this paper ([Warton & Hui 2011 Ecology](http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/10-0340.1) pp9):

> For non-binomial proportions, there was never any theoretical reason
>   to use the arcsine transform in the first place, and we instead
>   suggest using the logit transform.

Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions in advance!

Comment: I think I would recommend trying an ordinal model, e.g. `clmm` from the `ordinal` package in R ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for the quick suggestion!! That's a nice alternative!

Comment: Hi @kctam.  I'm in a similar situation.  What did you wind up doing?

Comment: @elduderino260 I ended up using `clmm`. Also you may check out the `glmmTMB` package for zero-inflation issues.